# HTTPBuilder Not Acceptable error

Tags: groovy, httpbuilder

I am getting this error but my method looks perfectly fine to me

```
def http = new HTTPBuilder()

http.request(
   'https://textalytics-topics-extraction-11.p.mashape.com/topics-1.2?txt=ben',    
   Method.GET,
   ContentType.JSON
) { req ->
    headers."X-Mashape-Key" = "mashkey"

    response.success = { resp, reader ->
        assert resp.statusLine.statusCode == 200
        println "Got response: ${resp.statusLine}"
        println "Content-Type: ${resp.headers.'Content-Type'}"
        println reader.text
    }

    response.'404' = {
        println 'Not found'
    }
}
```

any ideas?

Comment: What error are You getting?

Answer (score 0):

Given that HTTP Not acceptable means:

> 406 Not Acceptable
>
> The resource identified by the request is only capable of generating
>   response entities which have content characteristics not acceptable
>   according to the accept headers sent in the request.

Then perhaps their API is finicky and you need to specify that you want the response to be JSON using the `Accept` header, using something like `Accept: application/json`.